# How to boost pulse audio maximum volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control, video-streaming

My laptop speakers have a very low volume and when I play local files, mostly using kodi, I managed to set the maximum volume higher achieving a volume that allows me to understand what people say on movies and videos.

The problem presents itself when I use a streaming services (eg netflix, youtube) on firefox: since there is no native way to boost the maximum volume on firefox I'm trying to find a way to boost the overall maximum volume on my linux system (Lubuntu).

With Windows I used the loudness equalization of my realtek driver, but the driver isn't available for ubuntu, I tried pavucontrol raising the maximum level of firefox and that of the output devices (laptop speakers) but the problem here is that when I adjust the volume (eg. temporary lower the volume while there is loud music on the movie and then raise it back) the maximum volume resets itself to 100% so it makes using paid streaming services very annoying to use.

Is there a way to permanently raise the range of the volume and put a fix, let's say 130% or 6/7 db maximum volume that doesn't change any time you lower back the volume?

Thank you

Comment: Run `alsamixer` and see if You can adjust the volume also there.